# Firebase Cloud Messaging How to Unsubscribe from Topic

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What is the restful API url to remove a token from a topic? I know that the POST api call to add a token to a topic is like the following:

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/{token}/rel/topics/{topicName}
```

Documentation is less than helpful when I want a simple list of restful endpoints that I can use from my server. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google support got back to me. `POST`'ing to a `batchRemove` did the trick, per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances).

`https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchRemove`

Answer (score 5):

Given that this is a REST API, so I'd expect a `DELETE` request to the same URL should work.

But I admit that the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#delete_push_subscriptions) is not very clear on this, so please report back if it works (or doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

Just confirming, that in order to unsubscribe from a topic you have to use

method DELETE:

`fetch('https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/'+tokenz+'/rel/topics/movies', {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'key=****'
          })`

If you are using `PHP` and `curl` instead of 
`curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );` you must use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");`